# How to properly subscribe for events

Tags: dapps

I am writing an application where I need to subscribe for certain SC events. Problem is that the wss connection is getting interrupted sometimes and re-connection needs to happen. I am loosing events that occur in the re-connection time frame.

So, question is, how to properly subscribe for events without loosing any? I'd prefer not to need a full archive node for this.